# handling error in the client side

Tags: anchor, anchor-client

How do we handle the custom errors returned from calling a function in the client side?
here is my function:

```
pub fn create_resume(ctx: Context<CreateResume>, name: String, age: u8, skills: Vec<String>) -> Result<()>{
        if name.len() > 20{
            return err!(Error::ExceedsLimit)
        }
        if age > 100{
            return err!(Error::ExceedsLimit)
        }
        if skills.len() > 10{
            return err!(Error::ExceedsLimit)
        }
        for skill in skills.iter(){
            if skill.len() > 10{
                return err!(Error::ExceedsLimit)
            }
        }
        let resume = &mut ctx.accounts.resume;
        resume.wallet = ctx.accounts.signer.key();
        resume.bump = *ctx.bumps.get("resume").unwrap();
        resume.name = name;
        resume.age = age;
        resume.skills = skills;
        Ok(())
    }
```

The error that I have defined

```
#[error_code]
pub enum Error{
    #[msg("Failed to verify authority")]
    Unauthorized,
    #[msg("Exceeds limit")]
    ExceedsLimit,
    #[msg("Skill doesn't exist")]
    DoesNotExist,
}
```

How do I handle the error in the client side?
can anyone show me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `try { } catch (e) { }` and check `e.message`. That should include the error msg. e.g. `"Failed to verify authority"`

```
try {
    const tx = await program.rpc.CreateResume(name, age, skills,{
       accounts: {
       payer: wallet.publicKey,
    },})
    console.log('Your transaction signature', tx)
} catch (e: any) {
    if e.message.includes("Failed to verify authority") { .. }
    else if e.message.includes("Exceeds limit") { .. }
    else if e.message.includes("Skill doesn't exist") { .. }
}
```